# How to handle multiple `GET` query parameters and their absence in Django ORM when filtering objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm currently building a blog, but this applies to a lot of projects. I have `articles` stored in `Article` model and have to retrieve them selectively as per the `GET` parameters.

In this case, I want to return `all` the `articles` if the `language` `GET` query parameter is not supplied and only the specified `language` `articles` when the parameter is supplied.

Currently I am doing the following:

```py
# articles/views.py
@api_view(['GET', ])
def articles_view(request):
    """
    Retrieves information about all published blog articles.
    """
    language = request.GET.get('language')
    try:
        if language:
            articles = Article.objects.filter(published=True, language__iexact=language).order_by('-created_at')
        else:
            articles = Article.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-created_at')
        # articles = Article.objects.first()

    except:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    serializer  =  ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True, exclude= ('content', 'author',))
    data = serializer.data
    return Response(data)
```

I feel this can be improved and condensed to a single `Article.objects.filter()`. The use of `if` for every query param seems inefficient.

This is especially required since the articles will later also be retrieved via `tags` and `categories` along with `language` in the `GET` query parameters.

With the expected condensed querying, there would be less `if` conditional checking and the freedom to include more query params.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: [Django rest framework filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)   Also, I'd use class-based views, as they nicely break apart base query (`queryset/get_queryset`) filtering `filter_class`, permissions, et c.

Comment: Also, sub-section [DjangoFilterBackend](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)

Comment: @RossRogers Thanks, I'll give it a try. Currently resolved it using `Q` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it using Django's [`Q objects` for building complex queries](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/query_relatedtool.html#how-to-use-q-objects-for-complex-queries).

https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/14omwl8/comment/jqdmf3n/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

### Request URL:

`http://localhost:8000/blog/?language=english&tags=guide&tags=seo`

### Response View:

I'm now also including multiple `tags` along with `language` in the `GET` parameters.

```
from django.db.models import Q

@api_view(['GET', ])
# @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated | HasAPIKey])
def articles_view(request):
    """
    Retrieves information about all published blog articles.
    """
    language = request.GET.get('language')
    # Multiple tags can be supplied in the GET parameter
    tags = request.GET.getlist('tags')
    
    # Query initialisation and default condition
    query = Q(published=True)

    # Checking for specific query parameters
    if language:
        query &= Q(language__iexact=language)

    if tags:
        # Tags have a many-to-many relation with 'Article'
        article_tags = Tag.objects.filter(slug__in=tags)
        query &= Q(tags__in=article_tags)

    try:
        articles = Article.objects.filter(query).order_by('-created_at')

    except:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    serializer  =  ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True, exclude= ('content', 'author',))
    data = serializer.data
    return Response(data)
```

I've included the full `view` for anyone who might be interested!

Answer (score 0):

The "Django way" to handle such things are Forms to clean your query params (ensuring the values are correct), then filtering using the cleaned data

```py
class ArticleQueryParamsForm(forms.Form):
    language = forms.CharField()

# articles/views.py
@api_view(['GET', ])
def articles_view(request):
    """
    Retrieves information about all published blog articles.
    """
    input_form = ArticleQueryParamsForm(data=request.GET)
    if not input_form.is_valid():
        return Response(status_code=400)

    articles = Article.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-created_at')

    language = input_form.cleaned_data.get("language")
    if language is not None:
        articles = articles.filter(language__iexact=language)
    
    serializer  =  ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True, exclude= ('content', 'author',))
    data = serializer.data
    return Response(data)
```

You can use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to combine the logic into one classe

```py
class ArticleFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = {"language": ["iexact"]}

# articles/views.py
@api_view(['GET', ])
def articles_view(request):
    """
    Retrieves information about all published blog articles.
    """
    articles = Article.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-created_at')
    articles = ArticleFilters(request.GET, queryset=articles)

    serializer  =  ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True, exclude= ('content', 'author',))
    data = serializer.data
    return Response(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seems like an interesting way, albeit a little complex. I'll try it next time. Currently resolved the issue using `Q` objects.